# List of OpenXmlAttributes name qualifiers?

Tags: excel, xml, attributes, openxml

Where can I find a list of OpenXML OpenXmlAttribute valid qualifiers for writing to Excel in C#? For example - new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str") sets the data type to string. The 't' being the type of attribute that I want to edit.

Where can I find the keywords for example bold/fontsize/fill, etc? I can't find any good documentation on this.